# Отображение рисунка загруженного с сервера

Tags: android

Есть приложение, в нем происходит подгрузка картинок с сервера и отображение их в ImageView. Картинки небольшие, в основном от 20x20 до 60x60. Проблема заключается в масштабировании на разных устройствах. Например, на SGS2 все такие рисунки отображаются как надо, в нужном масштабе. Но вот на SGS4 эти же самые рисунки выглядят очень мелко. Пробовал масштабировать с помощью Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(), рисунок увеличивается, но явно теряет качество. Есть ли возможность их увеличить в зависимости от разрешения экрана устройства без потери качества?

Comment: лучше заготовить картинки под конкретные разрешения.

Comment: Вы совершенно правы, но здесь это решение, к сожалению, не подходит. Может быть есть другие варианты?

Comment: это только в американских фильмах могут увеличить фотографию машины, сделанную через отражение в луже темной ночью и увидеть на ней номер. В реальной жизни это далеко не так.

Но в случае некоторых изображений можно попробовать сделать красивое увеличение. Но это сильно зависит от изображения. Может покажете картинки?

Comment: Может тогда грузить 60*60 и при необходимости их уменьшать? либо взять такое разрешение, при котором увеличение не критично (для уменьшения трафика), а для меньших уже уменьшать масштаб.

Comment: ага, и пусть пользователи слабеньких девайсов позагорают на солнышке, пока их девайсы будут скачивать больше и ещё конвертить.

Comment: @KoVadim, Эти рисунки - смайлы. Например, вот: http://smages.com/images/smiley1.gif

Comment: @BArtWell не совсем так: http://habrahabr.ru/post/136853/

Answer (score 1):

Подготовить картинку заведомо больше, а при запросе к серверу

> На устройстве узнаем значение ppi, и

грузим нужные картинки и на стороне сервера уменьшаем картинку до требуемых размеров. Размеры изображений маленькие так что не думаю что нагрузка будет большая, ну и кеширование ни кто не отменял.

Comment: > @KoVadim: Вы совершенно правы, но здесь это решение, к сожалению, не подходит.
или к серверу вообще доступа нет?

Comment: я так понимаю,  на сервере есть картинки и все. залить/убрать нет возможности.

Comment: ну я не предлагаю их заливать/удалять, я предлагаю не напрямую к картинке обращаться, а к, скрипту что-ли, на PHP например, который при получении значения ppi и ID картинки вернёт уже изменённую под этот ppi картинку

Answer (score 0):

Все просто:

1. На сервере готовим рисунки под необходимые разрешения (`ldpi`, `mdpi`, `hdpi`....)
2. На устройстве узнаем значение `ppi`, и в соответсвии с этим - грузим нужные картинки.
3. Profit

Comment: Вы видимо мой самый первый коммент не читали? и ответ @BArtWell на него. Оно ему не подходит.

Answer (score 0):

Найдите такой размер, чтобы на SGS4 и на планшетах качество картинки вас устраивало, её и отдавайте с сервера. В приложении в свойствах ImageView пропишите:

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="40dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp" />
```

(Вместо 40dp установите подходящий вам размер)

Теперь по идее у вас на любом экране смайлы будут одинакового размера, на устройствах с маленьким экраном они будут уменьшаться.

Думаю, при современных скоростях интернета нет особой разницы, загружать картинки весом 10Кб или 40Кб.

Comment: ну да, какая разница, загружать мегабайт или 250 килобайт (кто же пользуется одним смайлом). Подождет пользователь, покурит...